# Historically has the "decoupling" of world trade from GDP not lead to (or deepened) a recession?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, international-trade, economic-history

The ECB [speaks](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/economic-bulletin/focus/2019/html/ecb.ebbox201905_01~874dddf42e.en.html) (somewhat euphemistically, in my opinion) of a "decoupling" of world trade from "activity" (i.e. GDP) in Q1 2019:

[image]

Historically, has it been the case that such a "decoupling" can last, i.e. not lead to a reduction in world GDP, i.e. to a global recession?